# Set a Zebra DataList Table

Tags: asp.net, css, datalist

First thing first, I need to bind a Table from the database so that each row would be editable. 
I decided to pick the DataList since it has `<EditItemTemplate>` property while the repeater doesn't have such.

I need to create a Zebra table and for that manner I've created the following CSS class:

```
.row:nth-of-type(odd)
{
background-color:Green;
}
```

The thing is that when I use this class in the repeater, it works fine since the repeater is built in such a way that you get to code the rows and the columns. 
For example:

```
<asp:Repeater>
<HeaderTemplate>
    <Table ...>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr Class="row">
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
  </tr>
</ItemTepmlate>
<FooterTemplate></Table></FooterTemplate>
```

[image: This is How the REPEATER table looks like]

BUT, when I build my DataList in the same way, it looks weird and messy.
So this is how my Datalist is built:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlStages" runat="server" DataKeyField="Priority" OnCancelCommand="dlStages_CancelCommand"
    OnEditCommand="dlStages_EditCommand" 
    OnUpdateCommand="dlStages_UpdateCommand" BorderWidth="2" 
     GridLines="Both" CellPadding="20" CellSpacing="20" Width="99%" 
    onitemdatabound="dlStages_ItemDataBound">

    <HeaderTemplate>

            <th>
                Priority
            </th>
            <th>
                Stage
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Command
            </th>
            <th>
                Expected End Date
            </th>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

            <td>
                <%# Eval("Priority") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("StatusName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("Comments") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("ExpectedEndDate", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>
            </td>

    </ItemTemplate>        
    <EditItemTemplate>

            <td>
                <%# Eval("Priority") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("StatusName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' Width="800px"
                    Height="48px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="update"></asp:LinkButton>
                /
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>

                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="txtDate"
                    TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy">
                </asp:CalendarExtender>
            </td>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

[image: DataList Table:]

In order to set the css class for each row in the DataList, I wrote in code behind the following code:

```
protected void dlStages_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.CssClass = "row";
}
```

The thing is that it doesn't create me a zebra table. instead it paints the first column (I have no idea where did it come from) in that Grey color.

Can anybody tell me what is the problem with my code? How to implement a ZEBRA table within the DataList control in my case?

Thanks in advance

P.S.
My question might be unclear so if clarification is needed, I'll explain in further detail.

Comment: I think you can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Answer (score 0):

See this related question: [Creating table inside Datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033317/creating-table-inside-datalist)

1. You haven't specified the `<tr>` tags in your templates, so the `DataList` is just generating orphan `<td>` tags
2. You can use the `RepeatLayout` attribute with a value of `Table` to have the `DataList` generate an opening and closing `<table>` tag for you.

Comment: I know that I didn't dpecify the <tr> tag. The reason is that when I do, it messes the whole table.
Now regarding your second answer, I've added the `RepeatLayout="table"` but it still didnt do what I was looking for.

Comment: Take a look at the last image in my post, I want that every odd row would be painted Green! How do I code this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but you should set the `ItemStyle` and `AlternatingItemStyle` properties of the `asp:DataList` in order to get the striping you want like this     `ItemStyle="normalRow" AlternatingItemStyle="greenRow"`

The start of your datalist tag should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.normalRow { background-color: white; }
.greenRow { background-color: green; }
</style>
<asp:DataList ID="dlStages" runat="server" DataKeyField="Priority" OnCancelCommand="dlStages_CancelCommand"
    OnEditCommand="dlStages_EditCommand" 
    OnUpdateCommand="dlStages_UpdateCommand" BorderWidth="2" 
     GridLines="Both" CellPadding="20" CellSpacing="20" Width="99%" 
    ItemStyle="normalRow" AlternatingItemStyle="greenRow"
    onitemdatabound="dlStages_ItemDataBound">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in the end, I decided to use js. I think that is the easiest and most intuitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bootstrap** classes in DataList control CssClass property:

```
CssClass="table table-striped"
```

Then, overwrite the table-striped:

```
.table-stripedCSS > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-stripedCSS > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
    background-color:red;

    /*Choose your own color here*/
}
```

For more info:
[Bootstrap table striped: How do I change the stripe background colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825211/bootstrap-table-striped-how-do-i-change-the-stripe-background-colour)